# How to fix resume issue: usbhid 2-4:1.0: can't add hid device: -110

Tags: usb, network-manager, suspend, acpi, wwan

Since I installed an Ericsson H5321gw 3G/GPS/HSPA+ WWAN module into a ThinkPad X1 Carbon running on 14.04.02 I'm seeing issues when resuming from suspend. More specifically, login both graphical as well as on Ctrl-Alt-F1 console will "stall", and delay for 30s or so, as if it was waiting for something.  dmesg shows what in my limited understanding is a resume issue of that newly installed hardware module:

```
usbhid 2-4:1.0: can't add hid device: -110
usbhid: probe of 2-4:1.0 failed with error -110
```

Here are lsusb details:

```
$ lsusb | grep Ericsson
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bdb:193e Ericsson Business Mobile Networks BV
```

Full relevant dmseg copy/pasted to http://pastebin.com/Rb3720VS.

How does one "fix" something like this??

Comment: Have you ever found found a fix?

Comment: @mat nope - I returned that WWAN module after a while.. ;-) (Just using tethering now, when needed.) Enjoy Scratch with your son! :)